# How to Insert Absolute panel in Google Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'd like help sorting out how(/if) I can insert an absolute panel (made using google apps script) into a google doc. I know how to make absolute panels already, and how to use apps script to add text, images, tables, etc to google docs. What I need is how to convert the absolute panel into an image or blob that I can transfer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not convert rendered UiApp result to image so the answer is no.